# Can't use a model using CarrierWave without a real file in Rails using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, carrierwave

I'm trying to run a test using a model, but I'm trying not to have to use a file for real here.

My use case is in rspec I try to create that object with a property handled by CarrierWave using FactoryBot, but I don't know what to pass to my `icon` property except a real file.

My model is like this:

```rb
class MyItem < ApplicationRecord
  validates :icon, presence: true

  mount_uploader :icon, MyIconUploader
end
```

Using FactoryBot, when I try to run `create` I have this error:

```
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Icon can't be blank
```

Only thing that works seems to be the following:

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :item, class: 'MyItem' do
    icon { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'assets', 'images', 'image.jpg')) }
  end
end
```

Giving it a file from memory would also work for me, as long as it is not a physical one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `StringIO` class for that. Since CarrierWave also expects a filename on the given IO object, you would also need to subclass `StringIO` to something like this:

```
class StringIOWithName < StringIO
  def initialize(stream, filename)
    super(stream)
    @original_filename = filename
  end

  attr_reader :original_filename
end
```

Then you can give an instance of `StringIOWithName` to Carrierwave.